# Difficulty starting the database in Netbeans using DB Derby and DBeaver

Tags: java, netbeans, derby, dbeaver

I am trying to make a DB Derby database in Netbeans called eportdatabase, and connect it to DBeaver. However, I am having trouble starting the database at all.

```
try
        {
                String databaseURL = "jdbc:derby:eportdatabase;create=true";
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseURL);
                Statement st = con.createStatement();
            
                if (!doesTableExists("Accounts", con))
                {
                    String sql = "CREATE TABLE Accounts (Username varchar(250), Password varchar(250)) ";
                    st.execute(sql);
                    System.out.println("Table Does Not Yet Exist!");
                }
                else if(doesTableExists("Accounts", con)) {
                    System.out.println("Table Already Exists!");
                }
                
                
                con.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

However, it does not work. When I run the application, this IOException Error Comes Up:

```
    java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database 'eportdatabase' with class loader jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@45ee12a7, see the next exception for details.
```

Is there something evidently wrong with my code? Or do I need to update my drivers (which I am having trouble doing)?

UPDATE: Thanks to help with printing errors from comments, I figured out the issue; I still had the old database folder in my application folder, which was present from before I updated to JDK 15, hence not being compatible with Netbeans' software. many thanks!

Comment: When it says `see the next exception for details`, follow these instructions to learn the true underlying cause of the problem: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/DERBY/UnwindExceptionChain

Comment: Please do not update your question with the resolution. That's not the way things are done here. Instead, please remove that update, post an answer to your own question and accept it.